# Find and Replace a section of a string with wildcard type search

Tags: c#, replace, find, wildcard

I want to be able to read a file, and replace all instances of:

M9S1800.2 with S1800  (I want to get rid of the M9 and the .2).

The problem I am having is that the 4 digit number after the "S" can be different every time, as well as the number after the decimal.

For example,

It can be:  M9S3200.1   or M9S5400.1   or M9S5400.2

Can someone please show me how to do this with C#?

I know how to find and replace by using this code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fDialog.FileName.ToString());
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();

content = Regex.Replace(content, "M2", "M3");
```

but with the M9S3200.1, I want to do a wildcard type replace.  For example it would be like replace M9S*.1 with S*   so M9S3200.1 would just become S3200.

Comment: glad you're getting help on regexes here. Here's a little pedantic help: C# does not have regular expressions, unlike JavaScript.

Comment: also, you should use `string content = null; using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReadeer(...)) { content = reader.ReadToEnd();}`. Cleans up even if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"M9(S\d{4})\.\d", "$1");
```