# how to manipulate string which contains different pattern in C#?

Tags: c#, string

i have a following type of string format ---

```
Proposal is given to {Jwala Vora#3/13} for {Amazon Vally#2/11} {1#3/75} by {MdOffice employee#1/1}
```

the string contains pair of **{ }** with different positions and may be n number of times.
now i want to replace that pair with other strings which i will compute depending on the string between **{ }** pair.

how to do this ?

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would be recomputing the contents of the { }s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try regular expressions. Specifically, `Regex.Replace` variants using `MatchEvaluator` should do the trick. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cft8645c(v=vs.80).aspx for more information.

Something along these lines:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Replacer
{
    public string Replace(string input)
    {
        // The regular expression passed as the second argument to the Replace method
        // matches strings in the format "{value0#value1/value2}", i.e. three strings
        // separated by "#" and "/" all surrounded by braces.
        var result = Regex.Replace(
            input,
            @"{(?<value0>[^#]+)#(?<value1>[^/]+)/(?<value2>[^}]+)}",
            ReplaceMatchEvaluator);
        return result;
    }

    private string ReplaceMatchEvaluator(Match m)
    {
        // m.Value contains the matched string including the braces.
        // This method is invoked once per matching portion of the input string.
        // We can then extract each of the named groups in order to access the
        // substrings of each matching portion as follows:
        var value0 = m.Groups["value0"].Value; // Contains first value, e.g. "Jwala Vora"
        var value1 = m.Groups["value1"].Value; // Contains second value, e.g. "3"
        var value2 = m.Groups["value2"].Value; // Contains third value, e.g. "13"

        // Here we can do things like convert value1 and value2 to integers...
        var intValue1 = Int32.Parse(value1);
        var intValue2 = Int32.Parse(value2);

        // etc.

        // Here we return the value with which the matching portion is replaced.
        // This would be some function of value0, value1 and value2 as well as
        // any other data in the Replacer class.
        return "xyz";
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var replacer = new Replacer();
        var result = replacer.Replace("Proposal is given to {Jwala Vora#3/13} for {Amazon Vally#2/11} {1#3/75} by {MdOffice employee#1/1}");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

This program will output `Proposal is given to xyz for xyz xyz by xyz`.

You'll need to provide your app-specific logic in the `ReplaceMatchEvaluator` method to process `value0`, `value1` and `value2` as appropriate. The class `Replacer` can contain additional members that can be used to implement the replacement logic in `ReplaceMatchEvaluator`. Strings are processed by calling `Replace` on an instance of the `Replacer` class.

Comment: i m trying for your solution . but it is not working. there is problem with regular expression .

Comment: @Priyanka: Sorry about that: I just corrected the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can split the string by '{' and '}' and determine the contents that way.

But i think a better way would be to find the chars by index and then you know the starting index and the end index of a pair or curly brackets so that way you can reconstruct the string with the placeholders replaced.

But the best method may be using Regex.Replace but that will only help to replace the placeholders with values you want but i think your requirement is to also parse the text inside of the curly brackets and based on that chose the value to be inserted so this won't work well perhaps. [Find and Replace a section of a string with wildcard type search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780023/find-and-replace-a-section-of-a-string-with-wildcard-type-search)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Regex.Replace Method (String, String, MatchEvaluator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ht1sxswy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method and the `{.*?}` pattern. The following example uses a dictionary to replace the values, but you may replace this with your own logic.

```
class Program
{
    static Dictionary<string, string> _dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _dict.Add("{Jwala Vora#3/13}","someValue1");
        _dict.Add("{Amazon Vally#2/11}", "someValue2");
        _dict.Add("{1#3/75}", "someValue3");
        _dict.Add("{MdOffice employee#1/1}", "someValue4");

        var input = @"Proposal is given to {Jwala Vora#3/13} for {Amazon Vally#2/11} {1#3/75} by {MdOffice employee#1/1}";

        var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"{.*?}", Evaluate);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    private static string Evaluate(Match match)
    {
        return _dict[match.Value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cannot you do something with `string.Format()`?

For example

```
string.Format("Proposal is given to {0} for {1} {2} by {3}", "Jwala Vora", "Amazon Vally", 1, "MdOffice employee");
```